# How does one cast a generic type in to a user-defined type?

Tags: java

**Context:** We've been tasked with making a small interpreter thing. One of the goals that we was hinted at was for us to not only work with variables of type `double`, but also to eventually be able to work with any type of variable.

Way I figured to do this was for to read in the `type` as a `String`, and have `value` set as a generic variable. Then we would cast `value` to whatever Type said it should be.

I could probably do a bunch of if statements of say...

```
if(type.equals("String")) { /*Cast Value to String*/ }
```

But that's so inelegant as to seem to be wrong. Also, what if the user were to define a new variable type? I don't think hard coding the possible `types` is the answer.

**Question:** Is there a way to, more or less, directly cast a generic variable in to a type that is inputted by the user?

Comment: Unrelated: in Java Variable names start lower case...

Comment: I know. I did it this way for readability's sake.

Comment: Don't do that, or people will think it's a static field.

Comment: Ah. OK. I'll fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are two parts to your problem.

1. Dynamically converting a user provided value to a type that is also provided by the user. I think this can be achieved by providing a `Type` interface that can have a `parse` method that converts a string to your `Type`. Each `Type` interface can also provide a name (like double or name etc.) which is entered by the user.
2. The second part - where you do not want to hardcode the available types can be achived by using Java SPI (service provider interface). Just google and you will get good examples. [One here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-spi).

Comment: Hmm. I'll  look in to the SPIs when I wake up. Sounds promising enough. But basically: There's no easy way to do what I am asking?

Comment: Easy is subjective. That said, SPI is really easy to use.

Answer (score -1):

i don't know what exactly do you need but in java you can find object types like this:

```
if (value.getClass() == String.class) {
    ....
}
```

and:

```
if (value instanceof Object) {
    ....
}
```

if you dont like to use bunch of if statements:

```
    switch (obj.getClass().getName()){
        case "java.lang.String":
            break;
        case "java.lang.Integer":
                break;
        default:

    }
```

and for cast your generic object to a custom type that given from user you can use this code :

```
        Object obj = "";
        String className = "java.lang.String";
        try {
            Class aClass = Class.forName(className);
            Object result = aClass.cast(obj);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

whit this code you can convert your object to your class name that give in string.

Comment: I didn't downvote your comment. However, the first part directly contradicts what I said I didn't want to do (a bunch of if statements for each type). And second, I may be incorrect, but I think that `String.getClass()` would just return a string, no matter what was said in the string..

Comment: if you dont like to use bunch of if statements you can use a switch case, i add it in my post

Comment: now you can use it in one line like your need if(obj.getClass().getName().equals("java.lang.String")) { /*....*/ }

Comment: you update your question and i think find your answer so i update my answer and i hope it can help you